# Displaying GEOJson/Dataframe information when mouse hover on a choropleth map

Tags: python, json, pandas, geojson, folium

I am coding an interactive Map of Chicago, and I am facing a big problem. What I would like is the possibily to display information (from the GeoJson file AND the Dataframe) when hovering an area.

Here is the code related :

```
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=CHI_geodata_url,
    name="choropleth",
    data=percan,
    columns=[percan.index,"TOTAL"],
    key_on='feature.properties.community',
    fill_color="YlOrRd",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Crime Rate (%)",
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['feature.properties.community'],aliases=['Community:']),
    highlight=True,
    show=True,
).add_to(CHI_map)

CHI_map
```

For now it doesn't display anything when I hover, but my objective is to have a pop up displaying the community name and the TOTAL number related to the area where the mouse is located.

Here is the json file :https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RandomFractals/ChicagoCrimes/master/data/chicago-community-areas.geojson

Does someone have an idea on how to do it ? I have spent the evening trying to find answers but without success.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found partially the answer with this piece of code :

```
    choro.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['community'],
    aliases=['Community Name'],
    style=('background-color: white; color: black;')
    ))
    display(CHI_map)
```

However, I can only display information contained in the geojson files. I am now looking for a way to display more information on hover not only contained in the json file but aswell in the data frame:

I have two leads :

- writing the data I want in the geojson file
- Finding a way to have pandas.Dataframe infomation displaying in the same time

I will try to update the comment if I find the answer, but if someone reading this know how to do it, feel free to help

Update:

I have found a way to add the information I wanted inside the geojson file thanks to this link https://towardsdatascience.com/using-folium-to-generate-choropleth-map-with-customised-tooltips-12e4cec42af2

```
      for f in range(len(percan)):
        tooltip_text.append(str(percan[crime_type][f])+' '+ '% of crimes')
        tooltip_text# Append a tooltip column with customised text
    i=0
    while i!= len(percan):
        for idx in range(len(percan)):
            if map_data['features'][idx]['properties']['community']==percan.index[i]:
                map_data['features'][idx]['properties']['tooltip1'] = tooltip_text[i]
            else:
                None
        i=i+1
```

A bit of explanation here :

```
      for f in range(len(percan)):
        tooltip_text.append(str(percan[crime_type][f])+' '+ '% of crimes')
        tooltip_text# Append a tooltip column with customised text
```

is to create a list with the things i want to display.

Then

```
  i=0
    while i!= len(percan):
        for idx in range(len(percan)):
            if map_data['features'][idx]['properties']['community']==percan.index[i]:
                map_data['features'][idx]['properties']['tooltip1'] = tooltip_text[i]
            else:
                None
        i=i+1
```

iterates through the entire dataframe 'percan' and make sure the value matches the community area in both dataframe.
The while insures we iterate through all the dataframe (even though I think I could have use a for), and then we take the first(i=1) row of our dataframe, look for its name in the geojson file (idx) and once it is a match we put the i value to the idx position in the geojson file